# allow query param with a dot in the value

Tags: routes, symfony4

I have the following route :

```
misc_email_availability:
    path: /email-availability/{email}
    defaults: { _controller: App\Controller\Misc\EmailAvailabilityAction }
    methods: [GET]
    requirements:
        email: .+
```

But when I hit `/email-availability/my-mail@domain.com` for example, symfony returns a 404, because of the `.` in the value, probably parsing it as a format, despite the fact I override the pattern in the requirements (as explained here to allow `/` in URLs : http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html)

Is there any way to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives me an error 500 on my local server (symfony 4.0.4) until I add the method name that you want to call after the controller name (**::methodName**) :

```
misc_email_availability:
    path: /email-availability/{email}
    defaults: { _controller: App\Controller\Misc\EmailAvailabilityAction::methodName }
    methods: [GET]
    requirements:
        email: .+
```

Here's my configuration :

**config/routes.yaml**

```
email:
    path: /check-email/{email}
    methods: [GET]
    defaults: { _controller: App\Controller\Admin\HomeController::email }
    requirements: 
        email: .+
```

**src/Controller/Admin/HomeController.php**

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;
[...]
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function email($email)
    {
        var_dump($email);
        die();
    }
}
```

Result of the call :  http://server.local/check-email/test@example.com

```
string(16) "test@example.com"
```

Hope it helps